# How to build a google keyword position tool

Tags: seo, google-custom-search, keyword-search

I have been searching for a tool to get around 400 keyword positions (google india) report of my website.
I have used around 10 tools to get the report, No tool is perfect enough to give the reports of all keywords at a time.

So I am planning to build a tool using any API's provided by google, I am not able get the report using Google CSE API also.

Please suggest me API's provided by google to build a tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google do not provide APIs to do this. In fact, they HATE people crawling their index for keyword positions and remove access to all APIs for anyone they discover doing so when tying it into another API-suite (for instance, RavenTools.)

If you want a keyword tool, I'm afraid you'll need to build a scraper from scratch or use one of the off-the-shelf options (which are all known by Google and in my experience consistently receive gamed results.)